# how to collapse a data frame based on a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame like this:

```
   symbol ls1   lsp10   ls02    ls6 
    a   ""  gh  ""  "" 
    a   ""  ""  ""  "" 
    b   ""  ""  gh  "" 
    df  ""  ""  ""  lm 
    b   gh  ""  ""  ""
```

how can I convert this to below table:

```
 symbol   ls1   lsp10   ls02    ls6 
    a   ""  gh  gh  "" 
    b   gh  ""  gh  "" 
    df  ""  ""  ""  lm
```

I tried below code but didn't worked

```
result <- aggregate(. ~ symbol, data = df, paste)
```

Comment: `result <- aggregate(. ~ symbol, data = df, paste0, collapse = '')`

Comment: try `aggregate(. ~ symbol, df, max)`

Comment: Thanks Ronak, it worked with your response.